# Why I cannot set 'Allow' in HTTP response header?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I've written a RESTful API using ASP.NET Web Api. Now I'm trying to make it returns the allowed verbs for a controller. I'm trying to do it with the following code:

```
[AcceptVerbs("OPTIONS")]
public HttpResponseMessage Options()
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
    response.Headers.Add("Allow", "POST");

    return response;
}
```

But instead of getting a Allow Header on my response, I'm getting a `500 Internal Server Error`. While debugging I receive the following error:

```
{"Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects."}
```

Is that possible to set that header?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As the error message says, you must use content headers with `HttpContent` objects.

```
response.Content.Headers.Add("Allow", "POST");
```

Must admit this is kinda weird API...

Comment: Yes, very weird! Thanks for sharing the answer!

Comment: Yeah.  It was considered a payload header in 2616 because apparently you could send it along with a PUT to actually change what methods were allowed.  Httpbis has changed it to be a response header, but it's too late for WebAPI!

Comment: This API just doesn't know what it is doing. I'm struck with a custom header from a vendor and it does not allow me to add the f***ing header. I guess I'd have to write a socket to get it working :|

Comment: If response.Content is null, add `response.Content = new StringContent("")`

Answer (score 3):

Allow is a content header.

```
        response.Content.Headers.Allow.Add("POST");
```

Comment: If response.Content is null, add `response.Content = new StringContent("")`